# Highchart - How to synchronize Highcharts horizontally and vertically in Angular 12?

Tags: highcharts, angular12

I am trying to synchronize multiple charts in both directions horizontally as well as vertically. I have synchronized charts vertically,  but Not able to synchronized charts horizontally in Angular 12. I have added below code. Which is currently synchronize vertically added Highcharts. I have added activity object which contains a graph data. I am calling the activity loop inside a ngOnInit method. In HTML added addHighlight method on mouse move , touch move and touch start.

[As I have added graphs in a row, I want all graphs in sync. Crosshair should move in all graphs if move the mouse or cursor.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPpEc.png)

HTML:

```html
<div>
    <div (mousemove)="addHighlight($event)"
         (touchmove)="addHighlight($event)"
         (touchstart)="addHighlight($event)">
        <highcharts-chart [Highcharts]="highcharts"
                          [options]="chartOptions1"
                          style="width: 100%; min-height: 228px; display: block;">
        </highcharts-chart>
    </div>
    <div (mousemove)="addHighlight($event)"
         (touchmove)="addHighlight($event)"
         (touchstart)="addHighlight($event)">
        <highcharts-chart [Highcharts]="highcharts"
                          [options]="chartOptions2"
                          style="width: 100%; min-height: 228px; display: block;">
        </highcharts-chart>
    </div>
    <div (mousemove)="addHighlight($event)"
         (touchmove)="addHighlight($event)"
         (touchstart)="addHighlight($event)">
        <highcharts-chart [Highcharts]="highcharts"
                          [options]="chartOptions3"
                          style="width: 100%; min-height: 228px; display: block;">
        </highcharts-chart>
    </div>
</div>
```

TS:

```js
activity = {
    xData: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    datasets: [
        {
            name: 'Widget 1',
            data: [2.5, 3.1, 3.3, 6.2, 1.41, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3],
            type: 'line',
        },
        {
            name: 'Widget 2',
            data: [2.8, 1.5, 2.1, 2.8, 1, 7.1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 7],
            type: 'line',
        },
        {
            name: 'Widget 3',
            data: [101, 98, 103, 6.87, 15, 7.11, 6, 3, 2, 9, 1],
            type: 'line',
        },
    ],
};
```

```js
this.activity.datasets.forEach((dataset, i) => {
    // Add X values
    const data = dataset.data.map((val, j) => [this.activity.xData[j], val]);
    this.chartOptions[i] = {
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'x'
        },
        title: {
            text: dataset.name,
            align: 'left',
            margin: 0,
            x: 100,
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false,
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false,
        },
        xAxis: {
            crosshair: {
                width: 3,
            },
            events: {
                afterSetExtremes: (event: any) => {
                    Highcharts.charts.forEach(chart => {
                        chart?.xAxis[0].setExtremes(event.min, event.max);
                    })
                }
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value}',
            },
        },
        yAxis: {
            crosshair: true,
            title: {
                text: null,
            },
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            style: {
                fontSize: '12px',
            },
        },

        series: [
            {
                data: data,
                name: dataset.name,
                type: dataset.type,
                fillOpacity: 0.3,
            },
        ],
    };
});


addHighlight(e: any) {
    let point, event;
    const charts = Highcharts.charts;
    console.log(charts)
    charts.forEach((chart, index) => {
        if (chart) {
            chart = charts[index];
            // Find coordinates within the chart
            event = chart?.pointer.normalize(e);
            console.log(event)
            // Get the hovered point
            point = (chart?.series[0] as any).searchPoint(event, true);
            if (point) {
                point.highlight(e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi @diksha bhosale, I've reproduced the issue in pure JS, but I am not sure what effect you want to get. Please refer to this live example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lumdnop4/ and let me know if anything needs to be improved.

Comment: In another word, I have a dashboard with multiple widgets charts placed in it ideally 2 widgets charts per row. I have around 4 rows for total 8 widgets charts. So,  the user should be able to see the cross line across all charts when hovering over one of them. Please see the image above.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I think this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uLczj293/ presents the required behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Still facing some issues.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-synced-charts-jyjuew?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Please refer  stackblitz example. I have used some code provided by @ppotaczek. In Angular 'this.childern[0]' is giving error so instead of this I have used 
customElements = document.getElementsByClassName('allCharts');
const chartIndex = customElements[0].firstElementChild.dataset.highchartsChart;
As you can see in my example, All charts are not synchronized when I move the cursor or hover on Widget 2 and Widget 4.

Comment: I am not an Angular expert, but you need to create a different HTML structure, similar like in the pure JS example. Live example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-synced-charts-fsinm2

Comment: Thanks for the help. Above example is working fine. I have some other issues. If  charts has a different widths how to synchronize that charts till last xAxis point? 
Please refer below example : 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-synced-charts-jyjuew?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: You can add a simple if statement and prevent the highlight in case of event coordinates outside the chart. Live example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-synced-charts-7ajumh